# javascript- Once I select a year, it should not be able to selected again (and is hidden)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-material

```
<div ng-repeat="localcost in vm.project.localCosts" layout="column">
         <md-select name="localcost_{{$index}}"ng-model="localcost.year" flex>
              <md-option ng-repeat="years in vm.getYears()" ng-value="years">{{years}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
</div>
```

The select box repeats according to the size of array localCost, so I get multiple selectbox. I am receiving years like (2015,2016..).

What I want is when I select a year then I can not select it again next time, here is a function inside the controller that is getting years that was already assigned before (start and end date):

```
function getYears() {
       // init start year
        var startYear = null;
        if ( angular.isDefined (vm.project.startDateObject._d) ) {
            startYear = parseInt(vm.project.startDateObject.format('YYYY'));
        }

       // init end year
        var endYear = null;
        if ( angular.isDefined(vm.project.endDateObject._d) ) {
            endYear = parseInt(vm.project.endDateObject.format('YYYY'));
        }

        // init budgets
        if (startYear && endYear) {
            var years = [];
            for (var i = startYear; i <= endYear; i++) {
                years.push(i);
            }
            return years;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @CaptainCarl Could you just deselect the other year? If there's an affordance of what the problem is (why the date is disabled), it may not be that bad

Comment: @CaptainCarl there is a delete button to delete that year

Comment: @HarisKhan does my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say call `ng-click` method & pass `year` value and then loop over `vm.getYears()` object then do add `isDisabled = true` property to found object.

and then do bind `ng-disabled` attribute over `md-options`

```
<div ng-repeat="localcost in vm.project.localCosts" layout="column">
     <md-select name="localcost_{{$index}}"ng-model="localcost.year" 
      ng-disabled="localcost.isDisabled" ng-click="selectYear(localcost.year)" flex>
        <md-option ng-repeat="years in vm.getYears()" ng-value="years">
           {{years}}
        </md-option>
     </md-select>
</div>
```